# Unfortunately cordova android App Stopped

Tags: java, android, cordova

**The application stops unfortunately with the Exception as:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference

**Occurrence of exception in my code**

```
package com.MyPhonegap.app;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String URL_ = "http://www.MyWebsiteUrl.com/";
        try{
            super.loadUrl(URL_);  // Line number x
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**My Log cat**

> 07-28 01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕
>   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.cordova.whitelist
>  07-28 01:20:20.519
>   2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>  07-28 01:20:20.519
>   2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>  07-28
>   01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>  07-28
>   01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>  07-28
>   01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ ... 25
>   more
>  07-28 01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app
>   W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not
>   found using the boot class loader; no stack available
>  07-28
>   01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app I/System.out﹕ Error
>   adding plugin org.apache.cordova.whitelist.
>  07-28 01:20:20.519
>   2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String,
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface,
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView,
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object
>   reference
>  07-28 01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:169)
>   07-28 01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins(PluginManager.java:95)
>   07-28 01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:84)
>   07-28 01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.init(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:116)
>   07-28 01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:150)
>   07-28 01:20:20.519    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:220)
>   07-28 01:20:20.520    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.MyPhonegap.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
>   07-28 01:20:20.520    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>  07-28
>   01:20:20.520    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   07-28 01:20:20.520    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>   07-28 01:20:20.520    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   07-28 01:20:20.520    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>   07-28 01:20:20.521    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   07-28 01:20:20.521    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>  07-28
>   01:20:20.521    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>  07-28 01:20:20.521
>   2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>  07-28
>   01:20:20.521    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>  07-28 01:20:20.521
>   2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>  07-28
>   01:20:20.521    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   07-28 01:20:20.521    2270-2270/com.MyPhonegap.app W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>   07-28 01:20:20.584    2270-2290/com.MyPhonegap.app W/EGL_emulation﹕
>   eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>  07-28 01:20:20.584
>   2270-2290/com.MyPhonegap.app W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa20a2fa0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: Please define your problem in detail how would any one help you without proper information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you instance of `CordovaPlugin` is unfortunately `null`

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Error shows that the Whitelist plugin is not added to your project. To add it to your project install it using this :

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

from terminal.

MainActivity.java

```
public class HelloWorld extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    }
}
```

Comment: Error remain same or changed ?

Comment: Edited my answer. Look my java class look like above.